# serial communication between raspberry pi and arduino via bluetooth

Tags: python, bluetooth

i get this message when i try to pair the above mentioned devices-
and i followed the instructions from 
http://blog.dawnrobotics.co.uk/2013/11/talking-to-a-bluetooth-serial-module-with-a-raspberry-pi/

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "bluetooth_serial_example.py", line 23, in <module>
print bluetoothSerial.readline()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 456, in read raise SerialException('device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected?)')
serial.serialutil.SerialException: device reports readiness to read
but returned no data (device disconnected?)
```

Comment: Please describe what you actually did in the question itself. What are the exact steps leading up to this problem?

Comment: I followed the instructions described in this link http://blog.dawnrobotics.co.uk/2013/11/talking-to-a-bluetooth-serial-module-with-a-raspberry-pi/ and i got the error message which i've already described

Comment: It's unlikely someone is going to read a long blog. Even if someone did that then they would need to try and guess which part of the blog in particular you tried and got stuck on. If you want others to help you then you need to make it as easy as possible for those reading your question. Provide all the info in your question (not as an external link) and make it as specific and yet concise as you can.